# merge command comparison between R and Stata

Tags: r, merge, stata

Being a R user, I am learning Stata now using [this](http://www.cpc.unc.edu/research/tools/data_analysis/statatutorial/example11) resource, and am puzzled about the `merge` command.

In R, I don't have to worry about merging data wrongly, because it merges everything anyway. I don't need to worry if the common columns contain any duplicates, because the `Y` dataframe will merge to each of the duplicated row in `X` dataframe. (using `all=FALSE` in `merge`)

But for Stata, I need to remove the duplicate rows from `X` before proceeding to merge.

Is it being assumed in Stata that, in order for `merge` to proceed, the common column in the master table must be unique?

Comment: for merging issues in Stata I find [MMERGE](http://econpapers.repec.org/software/bocbocode/s420201.htm) really useful.

Comment: FYI: Starting with Stata 11, the features of `mmerge` have been incorporated in the "official" `merge` command.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to your question is No. I will try to explain why.

The link you mention covers only one type of merge that is possible with Stata, namely the one-to-many merge.

`merge 1:m varlist using filename`

Other types of merge are possible:

One-to-one merge on specified key variables

`merge 1:1 varlist using filename`

Many-to-one merge on specified key variables

`merge m:1 varlist using filename`

Many-to-many merge on specified key variables

`merge m:m varlist using filename`

One-to-one merge by observation

`merge 1:1 _n using filename`

Details, explanations and examples can be found in `help merge`.

If you do not know if observations are unique in a dataset, you can do the following check:

`bysort idvar: gen N = _N`

`ta N`

If you find values of N that are greater than 1, you know that observations are not unique with respect to idvar.

This is in fact the new syntax of the `merge` command that has been introduced with Stata 11. Before Stata 11, the merge command was a bit simpler. You simply had to sort your data, and then you could do:

`merge varlist using filename`

By the way, you can still use this old syntax in Stata 11 or higher.

Comment: Good job with a pretty comprehensive answer.  Note that the older syntax was simpler but they changed it because it caused all sorts of hard-to-detect problems when your data was not as expected.  Using the old syntax still works but returns a warning.

Comment: @gsk3: Good comment. Personally, it took me some time to adopt the new merge syntax in my programs and classnotes. The new syntax looks and feels at a first glance more complicated. However, it will pay off quickly as it may draw your attention to problems in the data.

Comment: It's a credit to Stata that they did something to make their language more difficult to understand at first but better in the long run.  Particularly since most of their customers don't come from programming backgrounds and therefore are unlikely to immediately get how much things like this (perhaps most akin to strong typing) improves their lives :-)

Comment: The command `isid` offers an easier way to test whether a variable is a unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

joinby, unmatched(both) is the command that corresponds to the R command merge.

In particular merge m:m DOES NOT do a many to many merge (ie full join) contrary to what the documentation implies.